# How to find numbers which are divisible by 3 in batch script file

Tags: batch-file

This is my code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /A i=1
echo "Enter 10 numbers"
:loop 
if %i% GEQ 6 goto end 
Set /p num= Enter number echo %i%:
set arr[%i%]= %num%
set /A i=%i%+1
goto :loop
:end

set /A j=0
:loop2 
if %j% GEQ 5 goto end2 
set /A num2=!arr[%j%]!
if !arr[%j%]! %% 3==0 (echo !arr[%j%]!)
set /A j=%j%+1
goto :loop2
:end2


pause
```

but it always crashed i want to finds numbers which are divisible by 3 i dont know what i am doing wrong and i am also new to batch scripting.

Comment: Arithmetic operations can only be done with the `SET /A` command. You cannot use them wit the `IF` command.

Comment: There is a very good [Batch language reference at SS64](https://ss64.com/cmd/).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine if a number is divisible by a factor of three is using the `Set /A` command. If you open up a Command Prompt window, type `Set /?`. and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, you should see, the arithmetic expressions. The one you need is the modulo operator `%`, which when used in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) must be doubled. If you use a modulo of three against your integers, the result will be the remainder. Therefore, a result of `0` means that the integer was equally divisible by a factor of three.

Perhaps this code will assist you further.

```py
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:AskNumList
Set "NumberList="
Set /P "NumberList=Enter 10 integers separated by spaces>"
(Set NumberList) 2> NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RC:"^NumberList=[0123456789]* [0123456789]* [0123456789]* [0123456789]* [0123456789]* [0123456789]* [0123456789]* [0123456789]* [0123456789]* [0123456789]*$" 1> NUL
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo :AskNumList

:PseudoArray
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Arr[) 2> NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "i=1"
Set "Arr[!i!]=%NumberList: =" & Set /A i += 1 & Set "Arr[!i!]=%"

:IsDivisibleByThree
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Arr[) 2> NUL"') Do (Set /A _ = %%G %% 3
    If !_! Equ 0 (Echo The integer !%%G! assigned to %%%%G%% is divisible by a factor of 3
    ) Else Echo The integer !%%G! assigned to %%%%G%% is not divisible by a factor of 3)

Pause
```

The first labelled section `:AskNumList`, requests your 10 integers, and only moves onto the next section if the correct number of integers are input.

The next labelled section `:PseudoArray`, creates individual variables for each input for further use within the script.

The last labelled section, `:IsDivisibleByThree`, performs the modulo calculation to determine if the value is a factor of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
@ECHO off
SET /p num="Enter the desired number: "
SET /a num1="(%num%/3)*3"
IF %num% EQU %num1% (echo The number is divisible by three.) ELSE (echo The number is not divisible by three.)
```

This works because Windows doesn't give you a decimal when dividing and will instead round, so what this does is it multiplies the inputted number by 3 and then divides it by 3. If the number is divisible by 3 then the two numbers will be the same and you will get an output that says so and vice versa.

Comment: That's not "rounding". It just omits the fractions. The term, programmers use for this behaviour is `to floor`. (btw: `set /a` doesn't need the percent signs to handle a variable and in this case even the parentheses are superfluent: `set /a num1=num/3*3` works the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for /L loop iterating at steps of 3 in conjunction with an if conditional comparison against each input value to increment a count only on match.

```bat
@Echo off
 Set "ValidateArray=For %%z in (1 2)Do if %%z==2 (Set /P "string=Enter 10 multiples of #: "&Set "_i=0"&(For %%i in (!string!)Do for /F "delims=" %%n IN ('set /a "_v=%%i %% #" 2^> Nul ') do if %%n equ 0 (set /A "_i+=1" & Set "!RV![!_i!]=%%i")) & if Not !_i! Equ 10 Goto :input)Else Set RV="
Setlocal EnableDelayedexpansion
:Input
 %ValidateArray:#=3%Arr
 Echo/input valid & Set Arr[
 Endlocal
```

Delayed expansion is used to protect against poison characters in the outer for %%i loop

Comment: Seems like an inefficient way to see if a number is a multiple of 3.  Why not just use the `MOD` option like the user was doing to test if the remainder is zero?

Comment: You could in theory change the `FOR /L` to `for /F "delims=" %%n IN ('set /a %%i %% 3') do @if %%n equ 0`

Comment: Checks out. I hadn't even bothered testing it. Definitely the more efficient proposition

Comment: updated, with minor modifications to the set /a command to guard against poison characters